# How do different sets of restrictions in a SEM with moderation affect results?

Tags: r, interaction, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, lavaan

I'm trying to run a latent moderated mediation analysis SEM with R lavaan. It is essentially "First Stage Moderation", per Edwards & Lambert (2007), with a few extra factors. I'm using the UPI approach with matching indicators to specify the latent interaction term, and the semTools package to probe interactions. I've come across several different methods of adding restrictions to the model (or not), and I'm hoping someone could provide clarity on why they are specified as such and what the implications are.

The first two methods are provided by Cortina et al. (2021) (https://doi.org/10.1177/1094428119872531), with code and data available at https://josecortina.com/, under "Section 3 Marsh et al R code". The last two methods are provided by Schoemann & Jorgensen (2021) (https://doi.org/10.3390/psych3030024), with code and data available at https://osf.io/npq24/. Both sources center (or DMC) product indicators, while the latter go on to probe simple slopes. The first Cortina et al. method (step 2 option 1, not shown here) provides no restrictions, following the UPI method from Marsh et al. 2004, and is straightforward. Here are the other methods I'm exploring:

1. Cortina et al., Section 3 Marsh et al R code, step 2, option 2 (formatting edited for clarity)

```
model.inter <- '
Afft1 =~ 1 * aff1t1c + aff2t1c
Trnt1 =~ 1 * ti1t1c + ti2t1c
Inter =~ 1 * a1t1 + a2t2

# structural model
NPVHC ~ Afft1 + Trnt1 + Inter 

# freeing error covariances for terms that share components 
# as implied by kenny and judd
aff1t1c ~~ a1t1
ti1t1c ~~ a1t1
aff2t1c ~~ a2t2
ti2t1c ~~ a2t2'
```

Here, covariances are freed between product indicators and their components. They also set reference indicators with loadings of 1, although I believe that is the default behavior of lavaan anyway.

2. Jorgensen, Example_mod, matching pair strategy

```
## Uses matched pair strategy. 
## Matched based on factor loadings in the ME model
modintMC2 <- '
tvalue =~ t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
sources =~ s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5
tip =~ tip1 + tip2 + tip3
int =~ t1s5 + t2s2 + t3s1 + t4s3  

#Estimate covariances between interaction and predictors
tvalue ~~ int
sources ~~ int

tip  ~ tvalue + sources + int
'
```

Here, rather than product indicators and component indicators, covariances are estimated between the latent interaction factor, the latent predictor, and the latent moderator.

3. Jorgensen, Example_mod_med. Note that this is the only method of the four that is explicitly geared toward moderated mediation.

```
  model1 <- "
f1 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
f2 =~ x4 + x5 + x6
f12 =~ x1.x4 + x2.x5 + x3.x6
f3 =~ x7 + x8 + x9
f3 ~ f1 + f2 + f12
f12 ~~ 0*f1 + 0*f2
x1 + x4 + x1.x4 + x7 ~ 0*1 # identify latent means
f1 + f2 + f12 + f3 ~ NA*1
newDV ~ b*f3
"
```

Here, the covariance between the latent interaction factor and the latent predictor and moderator factors is set to 0, reference indicators are set to intercepts of 0, and latent means are freely estimated.

All three methods shown (plus the unrestricted example from Cortina et al., not shown) seem to be addressing the same issue of latent moderation, so I'm wondering why there are so many different approaches. What is the practical difference between allowing covariances between product indicators and their components in example 1 vs between the latent interaction factor and its latent components in example 2? Why is the latent interaction allowed to covary with its components in example 2, but not example 3? And why are reference indicators set to intercepts of 0 and factor intercepts freely estimated in example 3, but not 2?

(If more code or context is needed, I'm happy to add it. It already seemed like a wall of text, so I stopped here.)

Thanks very much.

**EDIT** - Updating this post with my findings so far and clarifying a couple of my questions.

- In the Cortina et al. example, they are skeptical of the [Marsh et al. (2004)](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/1082-989X.9.3.275) unconstrained method, and add covariances between product indicators and their components as from [Kenny and Judd (1984)](https://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/0033-2909.96.1.201) These makes enough sense, and these methods don't seem to be particularly settled yet.
- As far as I can tell, setting `x1 + x4 + x1.x4 + x7 ~ 0*1` in example 3 (Jorgensen, Example_mod_med) sets reference indicators to means of 0, allowing means of latent variables to be freely estimated. I'd love to hear if I'm interpreting this properly, though.
- The biggest question I still have is why Cortina et al. (implicitly) allow for covariances between the interaction factor `Inter` and its component factors `Afft1` and `Trnt1`, while Jorgensen (explicitly) fixes the covariance between the interaction factor `f12` and its component factors `f1` and `f2` to 0. Is this theory-driven, based on the research questions and a priori hypotheses in these studies? Or is it disagreement over whether (double-mean) centering of component indicators sufficiently reduces the covariances between latent factors and their latent product?